# how to directly import RxJs module to Browser after Typescript compilation (without Angular, Webpack, LiteServer)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have my RxJs code working on Node, currently it compiled to Script.js what started after TS compilation with lines

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var rxjs_1 = require("rxjs");
var operators_1 = require("rxjs/operators");
...
```

Currently I want to start my code on Browser
Of course, as first step need to overcome module support on Browser, in order to this first script is

```
<script>var exports = {};</script>
```

I don't know how is correct theoretically, but its working.
Second step for me, is install and configure Require.JS, for example in this way

```
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
      paths: {
          "rxjs": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js",
          "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min"
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    require( ["jquery"],
      function ($) {
        console.log($("#myButton").val())
      }
    );
  </script>
```

jQuery not need for me currently, I simple check how Require.JS working with it. Yes, working fine.
But next step is link correctly RxJS and RxJs/Operator - and I how to do this correctly?
For example I replace () to [] in my Script.JS - this is requirement of ReqjireJS, it started from

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var rxjs_1 = require["rxjs"];
var operators_1 = require["rxjs/operators"];
...
```

But Browser said "Uncaught TypeError: rxjs_1 is undefined", this mean RxJS not loaded and it's function not defined. How to overcome this (and of course not root namespace of RxJS but also RxJS/Operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to split them into `rxjs/operators` and `rxjs`, all are present in the single object `rxjs`, please find below working example:

```js
requirejs.config({
    appDir: '.',
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
      rxjs: ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min'],
    },
  });

  require(['rxjs'], function (rxjs) {
    console.log('Loaded :)');
    // simple
    rxjs.of(true).subscribe(console.log);
    // complex!
    rxjs
      .of(true)
      .pipe(
        rxjs.switchMap(() => rxjs.of('qwerty'))
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.9/require.min.js"></script>
```